# Why is POWER(2, 32) throwing an error? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried using the SQL POWER Function

```
SELECT POWER(2, 32)
```

and it returned this error

> Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 21
>   Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 4294967296.000000.

Why does it throw this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

The `2` in `SELECT POWER(2, 32)` is an `int`, and the largest value an `int` can store is 2,147,483,647. 4,294,967,296 is too large for that.

Convert your `int` to a `bigint`.

```
SELECT POWER(CONVERT(bigint,2), 32);
```

From [POWER (Transact-SQL) - Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types):

> The return type depends on the input type of *float_expression*:
>
> ```
> Input type                              |Return type
> ----------------------------------------|--------------
> float, real                             |float
> decimal(p, s)                           |decimal(38, s)
> int, smallint, tinyint                  |int
> bigint                                  |bigint
> money, smallmoney                       |money
> bit, char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar     |float
> ```

Comment: Will add about smaller data types, but statement about that because `2` is an `int` is the reason this fails *is* correct, @MartinSmith . This will always be the case, using `POWER` on an `int` will never allow a value larger than 2,147,483,647 to be returned.

Comment: Yep I agree. I was just pointing out that the implication that the return type was an `int` because `2` is an `int` is not as simple as just the return type  being that of the first argument to `POWER` (as might be assumed). It requires reference to the table you have now added to your answer

Comment: Fun fact: the docs didn't use to say this until I submitted an amendment. They used to say that the output type was the same as the input type, which is true only in a minority of cases, and even then horribly misleading for `decimal` (where the precision gets botched). Long live the era of editable content.

Comment: Since the documents have become open to community corrections, they've had a vast improvement, @JeroenMostert . There were a lot of mistakes in the old ones. It's been really good the see the communities contribute to it's corrections, but also it's evolution.

Comment: And still I would much prefer it if I could submit a pull request to the engine so the behavior could be changed to not require a detailed table with weird exceptions... but I realize that that's unrealistic even if it were open source, due to the dreaded demand for backwards compat. :-P